# Is it ok to ask Moderators to delete off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, declined-flags

I flagged an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548780/which-free-database-with-replication-support) which I believe to be off-topic asking for it to be deleted. Since this is not something that I can perform myself I deemed it to be a valid reason for moderator flag. If I voted to close this myself, my vote would probably have expired. The close vote review queue is usually not handling any old questions. Besides, the result I wanted to achieve would not be achieved just by closing the question. I would need to find 2-4 more people willing to help me delete this and the whole process would take more than 2 days.

The flag got declined with a custom reason:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

What should I have done in this situation? There is no flag for *"Please delete the question because it is off-topic"*

Comment: Why does it need to be deleted immediately if it's closed. Roomba will likely delete it at some point so why worry?

Comment: @RobertLongson Roomba does not handle upvoted questions.

Comment: Questions are upvoted because they are useful. You're going against what other people want if you want to delete upvoted questions. Why should your wishes outweigh theirs if there are more of them then there are of you?

Comment: @RobertLongson "Questions are upvoted because they are useful" [citation needed]. I've asked many useful questions and not all of them get hundred of upvotes.

Comment: Your actual flag text was: *The question is a problem. It is off-topic and the whole thing should be deleted. It attracts low-quality answers*. That's what closure is for, to deal with off-topic questions that should not be answered. Note that you **didn't ask us to do anything**, we had to make assumptions as to what you wanted the moderators to *do* with the post. Don't just tell us that there is a problem with a post, try to be explicit in what you expect to happen in such cases. "The whole thing should be deleted" is not being explicit.

Comment: @braiam read the tooltip when you hover over the up vote arrow

Comment: @RobertLongson plot views / votes on questions and you would see a pretty straight line.

Comment: Why was the question you flagged suddenly so important? It [hadn't see a vote, an answer, close-vote, or *any* activity in > *11.5 years* (the most recent activity prior to this meta question was 2009-02-14)](//stackoverflow.com/posts/548780/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries). You didn't even *try* casting a close-vote until after you posted this Meta question. Yes, the CV queue probably wouldn't have actioned this old, almost never visited question, but you didn't *try*. If it wasn't worth you casting a close-vote, why did you think it was worth moderator time to close and delete it for you?

Comment: In addition, saying "it attracts low-quality answers" in your flag feels disingenuous, given no new answers in 11+ years.

Answer (score 27):

No, it is not OK to raise a moderator flag. Regardless of age, off-topic questions should be *closed* first, even if they are later deleted. You do not need to involve a moderator to get a question closed, nor should you.